# Any provider of signed financial data (SXG or JOSE)?

Tags: http, digital-signature, finance, tls1.3, jose

Do you know any financial data APIs supporting [signed HTTP exchanges](https://wicg.github.io/webpackage/draft-yasskin-http-origin-signed-responses.html) (SXG), [JOSE/JWS/JWE](https://jose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or any other digitally signed format to provide verified financial data (stock market data)?

The following researches gave no answer:

- HTTPS responses can't be used as signed messages because [TLS doesn't provide non-repudiation](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/231014/is-it-possible-to-store-record-https-client-auth-traffic-as-a-signed-document/231019#231019).
- Kraken provides [PGP public key](https://www.kraken.com/features/security/pgp) but it's only used to sign official email correspondence.

Comment: It's hard to understand your use case and context. Can I ask why the security on the transport layer isn't sufficient for you?

Comment: @aholbreich It would be useful for digital financial instruments to verify the signature and provide the [non-repudiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-repudiation) without the involvement of a third party. For example, for [blockchain oracles](https://chain.link/education/blockchain-oracles) or blockchain-based forward contracts.